# How to generate a random pair of numbers in a loop without duplicate pairs

Tags: c, random

I want to make a program where on a 8x8 2D array, I input an integer from 0 to 64, and it will place that amount of 'Z' on the array randomly. I can't figure out how to generate a loop of pair of random numbers that do not have any duplicate pairs. Since the pair of random numbers generate will represent the position in the 2D array where the 'Z' will be placed, there should be no duplicate pairs generated so that all the 'Z' are printed.

Comment: if numbers are from zero to 64 first fill the table with `-1` and then you can see if the particular element was already taken or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem is only of size 64, an efficient way of doing this can be to:

1. Create an array of 64 items. Each item corresponds to one position in the grid. For example the item at index 0 will correspond to row with index 0 and column with index 0. The item at index 63 would be at row with index 7 and column with index 7, and so on. Generally speaking, the formula to map the location of the array to the grid would be: `Ai = Gr * grid columns + Gc`, where `Ai` is the i-th element in the 1D array of items, `Gr` is the r-th row in the grid and `Gc` is the c-th column of the grid.
2. Place `n` times the letter `'Z'` in the array, where `n` is the user's input. You can place them all for example in the first `n` places of the array of items.
3. Shuffle the array randomly. For example you can shuffle it by performing random indices' permutations (swaps).
4. Place the `'Z'` letters from the array to the grid using the inverse of the formula from step 1, ie: `Gr = Ai / grid columns` and `Gc = Ai % grid columns`.

You can probably also do this without the need for the temporary array of step 1 at all. Just translate each coordinate on the fly.

See also: [Choosing random cards from a deck?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389119/choosing-random-cards-from-a-deck) for a related problem.